# Strange result when dividing two numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql, division

This code:

```
DECLARE @remise decimal(10,2) 
set @remise = 10 / 100
select @remise
```

results in 0.00. Why doesn't it result in 0.10, which I have been expecting?

Comment: This is an English speaking site, please translate your question to English

Comment: And when asking SQL questions, tag your request with the DBMS you are using. While 10 / 100 = 0.1 in most DBMS, some DBMS (like SQL Server) apply an integer division here where 10 / 100 = 0.

Answer (score 3):

You have two integers - `10` and `100`. So when considering the division operator, the system decides to perform integer division. Integer division disregards any remainder and cannot produce a decimal result, so the result is `0`.

It doesn't matter that you're subsequently planning to store the result in a `decimal(10,2)`.

*One* way to solve it would be to use a non-integer as one of the inputs to the division. If you're not using literals, commonly this can be done by multiplying one of the inputs by `1.0`:

```
DECLARE @remise decimal(10,2)
set @remise = (10 * 1.0) / 100
select @remise
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this SQL Server?

10 and 100 are both integers. The integer division 10 / 100 results in 0. If you put that 0 into a decimal variable, the zero still stays zero.

You want

```
DECLARE @remise decimal(10,2)
set @remise = 10.0 / 100.0
select @remise
```